# Datadog monitor alerting for N/A

Tags: alert, monitor, datadog

I am using datadog monitors to alert but it is alerting even in the **case of N/A**. I used the **exclude_null** function but still received the alerts. For some N/A it alerts while for others does not.

[image]

[image]

**Query**: sum(last_1h):exclude_null(exclude_null(sum:xyz.abc.count{status:failed} by {id}.as_count()) * 100 / exclude_null(sum:xyz.abc{status:complete} by {id}.as_count())) > 30

Can anyone please let me know if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't know that datadog has Renotification tab.

[image]

The tab works if alert of monitor has been triggered.